# Package of 'bidi.sty'

Tags: lyx, hebrew

I'm trying to compile a hebrew Lyx file on Linux, and I get an error that the file 'bidi.sty' is not found. Which package has this file? I'd like to install it and see if it works...

Comment: According to the [CTAN page on `bidi`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bidi) you are looking for the (aptly named) `bidi` package in both MikTeX and TeX Live.

Comment: @moewe I tried to install it, but the terminal says that it was unable to locate that package.

Comment: How did you try installing it? Via `tlmgr` (TeX Live)/Package Manager (MikTeX) or manually?

Comment: @moewe I wrote sudo apt-get install bidi. How can I try it through tlmgr?

Comment: Aha! `sudo apt-get install bidi` will probably not work, if you got TeX Live trough your Linux repositories, you will have to find the Linux package that includes `bidi.sty`. `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` should help but will install lots of files, can't you use `apt-get`'s search function to fin out which package includes `bidi`?

Comment: The package `texlive-lang-arabic` should be enough.